# Error running Learn Perl (learn.perl.org) example for reading a directory

Tags: perl

learn.perl.org has example code for [reading the contents of a directory](http://learn.perl.org/examples/directory_list.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;

my $dir = path('foo','bar'); # foo/bar

# Iterate over the content of foo/bar
my $iter = $dir->iterator;
while (my $file = $iter->next) {

    # See if it is a directory and skip
    next if $file->is_dir();

    # Print out the file name and path
    print "$file\n";
}
```

Running it with Perl 5.18.2 and Path::Tiny of DAGOLDEN/Path-Tiny-0.104.tar.gz, I get an error:

> Can't call method "next" on unblessed reference at read_directory.pl
>   line 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a simple mistake on the learn.perl.org example: the example in the [Path::Tiny docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#iterator) is correct. The iterator is a function, not an object; it produces values using `$iter->()`, not
`$iter->next`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're right. It seems that this example was changed to use Path::Tiny in the last few days and this error slipped in at that point.

I've submitted a pull request to fix it.

https://github.com/perlorg/perlweb/pull/233